# How to filter Items in Recommender Systems?

Tags: recommender-system, named-entity-recognition, matrix-factorisation, similar-documents

I have a Recommender System which recommends Articles based on Similarity from 3 Features, "Page-Title, Article Content, Tags". But some of the Articles are NSFW(Related to Adult Topics). I want to keep these Recommendations separate from the normal ones? Any idea about how do I go ahead with it,

I was thinking about keeping the adult articles separate and using another metric to recommend them, but I do not feel its right as it would create a whole different Recommender System.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you cannot filter NSFW articles as a post-processing step? For instance, if you need to recommend 10 articles, you find the top 50 recommendations and then apply the filter if it is needed and truncate down to top 10?

In my experience, it is pretty common to apply business rules before/after recommendations to account for things like this. Grabbing an example article on this topic for reference:

https://buildingrecommenders.wordpress.com/2015/11/10/the-components-of-a-recommender-system/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, that is what I have planned if nothing else works but then I am not using the implications of that article for other recommendations. I am just looking at a better way to do it.